# Which JVM do I have?

Tags: java

I have heard that some JVMs are significantly faster than others. Especially HotSpot is told to be very fast.

But which JVM do I already use?

```
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_20"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.9.13) (6b20-1.9.13-0ubuntu1~10.04.1)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 19.0-b09, mixed mode)
```

Which JVM get used in the [free official download](http://java.com/en/download/index.jsp)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the [IcedTea](http://icedtea.classpath.org/wiki/Main_Page) build of the [OpenJDK](http://openjdk.java.net/) [JRE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Runtime_Environment), which is based mostly on the same code base used by the "official" version from Oracle.

- Put simply, you are using the IcedTea JVM.
- Hotspot is provided by the "official" download
- **But** IcedTea is *based on Hotspot!* ([see their homepage for details](http://icedtea.classpath.org/wiki/Main_Page))

  - The only difference is that IcedTea has a separate (open-source) browser plugin!